# First order ODE problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$2y'+3y = 0$$

So my integrating factor $p(x) = 3$. So I multiply both sides by $$e^{\int 3 \ dx}$$

And get $$e^{3x} (2y'+3y)=0$$

I now have to integrate both sides but the trick is that I get my $$e^{3x}$$ times my $y$ so I should get $$e^{3x} \cdot y = 0$$

But the solution according to wolfram alpha is $$y(x) = e^{-3x / 2}$$

What am I doing wrong? Also why is this subject taught so trivially without any depth? ''just multiply both sides by the magical integrating factor and then integrate both sides and watch the sorcery commence.''

Thanks.

Comment: Your integrating factor should be: $e^{\int \frac{3}{2}\:\mathrm{d}x}$, remember that you should try and make the coefficient of the derivative equal to $1$ (in this case by dividing through by $2$).

Comment: What do you mean I want the coeffecient to equal one? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Well as noted in Sami's answer, the solution family to the differential equation: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha(x)y$$ Is: $$y(x)=Ce^{\int a(x)\:\mathrm{d}x}$$ And you see in order for this to work, there must be no coefficient of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et4Y41ZNyao

And he just says: ''Find p(x)'' which in my case would be just 3 as there is no x...Then integrate and multiply, done.

I hate this subject...

But thank you

Comment: But notice that he writes the equation as: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+P(x)y = Q(x)$$ In order to fit this equation you need to divide through by $2$, else you will have $2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$. This gives $P(x)=\frac{3}{2}$ and $Q(x)=0$.

Comment: What does your equation represent?

What is alpha of x times y?

Comment: In my initial equation $\alpha(x) = -P(x)$, is this what you're asking?

Comment: Yes. You wouldn't be able to shed some light on what is going on or link me some material that does? Every single video I look up just tells me to mechanically apply this and that to arrive to a conclusion. I'm interested in what is actually going on.

Comment: There is a book called [Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Methods-Physics-Engineering-Comprehensive/dp/0521679710) which describes how to discover the integrating factor solution for inexact ODEs (the more general form of the linear ODE you are studying), it is quite interesting, but there may be other sources which are better. Perhaps you could ask in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13574/room-for-general-mathematical-conversation)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The solutions of the linear differential equation
$$y'=a(t)y$$
are
$$y(t)=\lambda e^{\int a(t)dt}\quad \lambda\in\Bbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor is just a function which allows us to make a given ordinary differential equation integrable. Say we have the differential equation 
           $y'+ fy =g$ where $y,f$ and $g$ are continuous functions of $x$. 
Now, let $h$ be a function equal to $\int f  dx$ , it follows that $h' = f$. By multiplying $e^h$ on both sides of the equation we get $e^hy'+ e^hfy = e^hg$. The product rule allows us to simpify this further, we get $(e^hy)'= e^hg$ since $(e^h)'= e^hh'= e^hf$. Now we integrate both sides and we obtain $e^hy =\int e^hg dx $ and then $y$ would be .....

Answer (score 0):

$$2y'+3y = 0$$
You don't even need to think too hard.

$$2\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=0$$
$$(2)\; dy=(-3y)\;dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{3}{2}dx$$

Integrate both sides:

$$\ln\big|y\big|=-\frac{3}{2}x+C$$

$$\therefore y=ce^{-\frac{3}{2}x}$$